# Is it possible for me to delve into number theory?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I have completed calculus courses but I have dropped out real analysis. However, I have basic knowledge of analysis and algebra to some extent like I know about group theory and about basic real analysis. I have also completed differential equations and basic linear algebra course.

Is it possible for me to start number theory as a self study at home without much difficulty. If yes, how? If no, Why?

I basically am aiming to read *Ramanujan's Notebooks* successfully.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to study Number Theory (admittedly, at a rather low level) without any university-level mathematics at all. I picked up Albert Beiler's book, [Recreations in the Theory of Numbers](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/319284.Albert_H_Beiler), when I was 12 and had a blast with it.

Now if you like your mathematics with theorems and proofs, you could still pick up Hardy and Wright, [An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers), or Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery, [An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~hlm/nzm/), and get through most of the book without much university-level math.

Getting to the level of Ramanujan's Notebooks, well, I'm not sure what you'd need for that. But you'll certainly need large chunks of what's in H & W, or in N, Z & M, so you might as well get started with one of those.

Comment: +1 for the H & W classic. I read it longtime ago, before (in hindsight) I was ready for it. Tough, great learning experience, and educational in so many ways.